# python extensions not available in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio

[image]I have searched python extensions in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, But its not available ,
can anyone please tell how to install python extension in that edition

Answer (score 0):

generally for me this method works in any version I have used (even 2019):
https://youtu.be/PmdbndOoKq4
but gives you an error?

Comment: for me - if I search Python means it's not showing the Python extension package in the window?  ADDING THE IMAGE FOR YOUR REFERENCE - please find in the Question Section